# mysql-mode in emacs error

Tags: mysql, emacs, settings

I am having a problem with mysql in emacs.

I went though the (sql-help) page in emacs, and says

> "Use the following commands to start a specific SQL interpreter...
>    **M-x sql-mysql**...
>   "

So I followed the instruction above.

1. M-x sql-mysql

Mini buffer goes interactive.

2. User: ? -> root
3. Password: ? -> *my password*
4. Database: ? ->
5. server: ? -> localhost

And at the end, it doesn't work, and says "**unable to locate SQL program 'mysql**' ".

I visited a lot of blogs, or manuals but couldn't figure out what it does mean, or why it does not work.

Comment: Do you have the mysql client installed on your machine? Can you run `mysql` from a shell, outside of Emacs? Is the directory for the mysql binary present in the Emacs `exec-path` variable?

Comment: To expand on phils' comment, Emacs doesn't contain any SQL clients. It contains tools that use existing clients installed on your machine, so you need the command-line `mysql` client installed in order to use `sql-mysql`.